# Django how to configure to use alternate static directory for admin

Tags: javascript, python, css, django, static

I would like to use an alternate static directory for admin's static directory. The links for javascript and css as used in the admin app show */static/admin/js* or */static/admin/css* in the uri.

I have copied over the *static/admin* directory to /Users/username/django_project/django_app/ directory. How can I now tell my app in the settings.py to use /Users/username/django_project/django_app/static instead? I realize this is not very good practice for production but am only interested in making some adds/changes to css and javascript so that it doesn't affect my django library for the Python environment I am using here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can now backup or move your *static/admin* directory and replace it with a symlink to new admin static path:

```
mv /static/admin /static/admin_old
ln -s /Users/username/django_project/django_app/static /static/admin
```